# From Mat to vector<Vec3f> and the other way around without corrupting the image

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, c++17

I need to use OpenCV in order to read an image, convert it into a vector of Vec3f, work with the pixels and then convert it back to Mat in order to visualize it.

I'm using C++17.

Here the code so far:

```
Mat* in = new Mat;
*in = imread(filepath);
int rows = in->rows;
int cols = in->cols;

//MAT -> VECTOR
vector<Vec3f>* src = new vector<Vec3f>(rows * cols);
if (in->isContinuous()) {
    src->assign(in->datastart, in->dataend);
} 
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        src->insert(src->end(), in->ptr<Vec3f>(i), in->ptr<Vec3f>(i)+cols);
    }
}

//---USE THE VECTOR TO TRASFORM EVERY PIXEL GRAY---

//SHOW 
imshow("out", cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8U, src, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP));
```

The result is a corrupted image, TV static noise like, even if i don't do the pixel processing phase

Thank you for the help

Comment: Show us what you do with the pixels and maybe the output in comparison with the original image.

Comment: @DimChtz I'm actually not modifying the image yet, just trying to make the conversion works

Comment: @joyfantastic if you take out the routine to turn the pixels gray, do you get the same image back?

Comment: @SCORP.io nope, something happens during the conversion

Comment: @joyfantastic - is there a guarantee that the rows are continuous?  The range you specify in your `insert` call would contain garbage otherwise.

Comment: @SCORP.io not really, how should i do it?

Comment: convert your Mat to floating point after imread by: cv::Mat floatMat; in->convertTo(floatMat, CV_32F); And dont use cv::Mat as pointer, if you dont have a good reason. cv::Mat is already something like a smart-pointer, because it only holds the header information and a reference counter to the data memory.

Comment: @Micka I'll try that, but I need to work with Vec3f

Comment: Vec3f are 3 32F values, so you can interpret the data as an array of Vec3f AFTER the conversion. Atm you are interpreting Vec3b memory as if it was Vec3f

Comment: @Micka do you mind writing a more incisive answer please? I did it but it isn't working and i'm pretty much stuck

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you need it as a `vector<Vec3f>`? You can "work with the pixels" of a `Mat` directly as well... | Also, why dynamically allocate the `Mat` and `vector` instances (and more so, why hold them in raw pointers... this is c++17 after all)

Comment: @DanMašek I'm grayscaling an image using my own method, which requires a vector of pixels; same thing regarding the dynamic allocation, it is required by my method; ... do you think that might be part of the problem?

Comment: @joyfantastic Ok. Don't think that's a problem here, but raw pointers introduce risk of memory leaks. Also working with pointers in general requires care.

Comment: sorry, was in airplane, but as I see your question alrady got answered. It works with .assign too, I'll post an answer that also covers the other way around (going from Mat to vector and back to Mat again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use a small random image for demonstration:

```
// Generate random input image
cv::Mat image(5, 5, CV_8UC3);
cv::randu(image, 0, 256);
```

### Option 1

Since the input is `CV_8UC3` (i.e. each element is a `cv::Vec3b`) and we want the elements as `cv::Vec3f`, we first need to use [`convertTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b), to convert the `Mat` to `CV_32FC3`. We store the result in a temporary matrix, and for convenience (since we know the element type) we can explicitly use `cv::Mat3f`.

```
// First convert to 32bit floats
cv::Mat3f temp;
image.convertTo(temp, CV_32FC3);
```

Now we can just use `Mat` [iterators](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33ee3bc402827f587a5ad64b568d6986) to initialize the vector.

```
// Use Mat iterators to construct the vector.
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> v1(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

### Option 2

The previous option ends up allocating a temporary array. With a little creativity, we can avoid this.

As it turns out, it is possible to create a [`cv:Mat` header wrapping a vector](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a23b182c4ffd46abe38f460c1480ae887), sharing the underlying data storage.

We begin by crating an adequately sized vector:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> v2(image.total());
```

The `Mat` created from such vector will have 1 column, and as many rows as there are elements. Therefore, we'll [`reshape`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8) our input matrix to identical shape, and then use `convertTo`, to write directly to the vector.

```
image.reshape(3, static_cast<int>(image.total())).convertTo(v2, CV_32FC3);
```

---

*Whole program:*

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void dump(std::string const& label, T const& data)
{
    std::cout << label << ":\n";
    for (auto const& v : data) {
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

}

int main()
{
    // Generate random input image
    cv::Mat image(5, 5, CV_8UC3);
    cv::randu(image, 0, 256);

    // Option 1
    // ========

    // First convert to 32bit floats
    cv::Mat3f temp;
    image.convertTo(temp, CV_32FC3);

    // Use Mat iterators to construct the vector.
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> v1(temp.begin(), temp.end());

    // Option 2
    // ========

    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> v2(image.total());
    image.reshape(3, static_cast<int>(image.total())).convertTo(v2, CV_32FC3);

    // Output
    // ======

    dump("Input", cv::Mat3b(image));
    dump("Vector 1", v1);
    dump("Vector 2", v2);

    return 0;
}
```

*Sample output:*

```
Input:
[246, 156, 192] [7, 165, 166] [2, 179, 231] [212, 171, 230] [93, 138, 123] [80, 105, 242] [231, 239, 174] [174, 176, 191] [134, 54, 234] [69, 25, 147] [24, 67, 124] [158, 203, 206] [89, 144, 210] [51, 31, 132] [123, 250, 234] [246, 204, 74] [111, 208, 249] [149, 234, 37] [55, 147, 143] [29, 214, 169] [215, 84, 190] [204, 110, 239] [216, 103, 137] [248, 173, 53] [221, 251, 29]
Vector 1:
[246, 156, 192] [7, 165, 166] [2, 179, 231] [212, 171, 230] [93, 138, 123] [80, 105, 242] [231, 239, 174] [174, 176, 191] [134, 54, 234] [69, 25, 147] [24, 67, 124] [158, 203, 206] [89, 144, 210] [51, 31, 132] [123, 250, 234] [246, 204, 74] [111, 208, 249] [149, 234, 37] [55, 147, 143] [29, 214, 169] [215, 84, 190] [204, 110, 239] [216, 103, 137] [248, 173, 53] [221, 251, 29]
Vector 2:
[246, 156, 192] [7, 165, 166] [2, 179, 231] [212, 171, 230] [93, 138, 123] [80, 105, 242] [231, 239, 174] [174, 176, 191] [134, 54, 234] [69, 25, 147] [24, 67, 124] [158, 203, 206] [89, 144, 210] [51, 31, 132] [123, 250, 234] [246, 204, 74] [111, 208, 249] [149, 234, 37] [55, 147, 143] [29, 214, 169] [215, 84, 190] [204, 110, 239] [216, 103, 137] [248, 173, 53] [221, 251, 29]
```

---

### Issues with your Code

1. In `src->assign(in->datastart, in->dataend);`

   Elements of `src` are `Vec3f`, however [`datastart`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aeda6d607bfc629a95f59e7b538832172) and [`dataend`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae756e84c94cbcf4c152ed0e67edb71ca) are pointers to `uchar`.

   This will have several consequences. First of all, since `in` is `CV_8UC3`, there will be 3x as many elements. Also, each of the `Vec3f` instances will only have the first entry set, the other 2 will be 0.
2. In `src->insert(src->end(), in->ptr<Vec3f>(i), in->ptr<Vec3f>(i)+cols);`

   Recall that you have already initialized `src` as `vector<Vec3f>(rows * cols);` -- i.e. the vector already has as many elements as there are pixels in the source image. However, in the loop you keep **adding** further elements at the end. This means that the resulting vector will have twice as many elements, with the first half of them being zeros.

   Furthermore, `in` is `CV_8UC3`, but you interpret the data as `cv::Vec3f`. This means you take the byte values of 4 consecutive pixels and intepret this as a sequence of 3 32bit floating point numbers. The result can't be anything else than garbage.

   It also means that you end up accessing data outside the valid area, potentially past the end of the buffer.
3. In `cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8U, src, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP)`...

   First of all, `src` holds `Vec3f` elements, but you're creating the `Mat` as `CV_8U` (which is also an issue, since you need to provide channel count here as well, so it's actually interpreted as`CV_8UC1`). So not only would you have the wrong number of channels, they would contain garbage due to type mismatch.

   Even bigger issue is that you pass `src` as the 4th parameter. Now, this is a pointer to the `std::vector` instance, not to the actual data it holds. (It compiles, since the 4th parameter is `void*`). That means you're actually interpreting the metadata of the `vector`, along with a lot of other unknown data. Result is garbage at best (Or as you found out, SEGFAULTs, or potentially nasty security bugs).

---

### Back to `Mat`

Note that it is possible to `imshow` a floating point `Mat`, assuming the values are normalized in range [0,1].

We can take advantage of the `Mat` constructor that takes a `vector`, and just reshape the resulting matrix back to the original shape.

```
cv::Mat result(cv::Mat(v2).reshape(3, image.rows));
```

Note that in this case, the underlying data storage is shared with the source `vector`, hence you need to assure it remains in scope as long the the `Mat` does. If you do not wish to share the data, simply pass `true` as a second parameter to the constructor.

```
cv::Mat result(cv::Mat(v2, true).reshape(3, image.rows));
```

Of course, if you want to go back to `CV_8UC3`, that's as simple as adding a `convertTo`. In this case there's no need to copy the vector data, since the data type changes and new storage array will allocated automatically.

```
cv::Mat result;
cv::Mat(v2).reshape(3, image.rows).convertTo(result, CV_8UC3);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i also have to convert the vector to mat after processing the elements! Mat(image.rows, image.cols, CV_32FC3, &v2, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP); returns a segfault

Comment: @joyfantastic Yes, that would definitely segfault. See point 3 at the bottom of my answer, this is the same scenario. I'll add example on how to do that correctly.  | This is some of what I meant by having to be very careful when you work with pointers. It's just so easy to shoot yourself in the foot. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version with .assign and .insert, similar to your given code. It also covers a unit test and the way from vector to Mat. And a way to test for non-continuous Mats, too.
I don't know which version ist faster, this one or the one from Dan Masek. Feel free to try.

```
int main()
{
cv::Mat in = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/Lenna.png"); // this is a CV_8UC3 image, which is cv::Vec3b format

cv::Mat inFloat;
in.convertTo(inFloat, CV_32F);

// choose this line if you want to test non-continuous:
//inFloat = inFloat(cv::Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));

int rows = inFloat.rows;
int cols = inFloat.cols;

std::vector<cv::Vec3f> src;



if (inFloat.isContinuous())
{
    std::cout << "continuous image data" << std::endl;
    src.assign((cv::Vec3f*)inFloat.datastart, (cv::Vec3f*)inFloat.dataend);
}
else 
{
    std::cout << "non-continuous image data" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < inFloat.rows; ++i) 
        {
            src.insert(src.end(), inFloat.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(i), inFloat.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(i) + inFloat.cols);
        }
}

// UNIT TEST:
bool testSuccess = true;
//const float epsilon = 0.01;
for(int j=0; j<rows; ++j)
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
    {
        cv::Vec3b & pixelIn = in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i);
        cv::Vec3f & pixelInFloat = inFloat.at<cv::Vec3f>(j, i);
        cv::Vec3f & pixelSrc = src.at(j*cols + i);

        if (pixelInFloat != pixelSrc)
        {
            std::cout << "different values in: [" << i << "," << j << "]: " << pixelInFloat << " vs. " << pixelSrc << std::endl;
            testSuccess = false;
        }
    }

if (testSuccess)
{
    std::cout << "conversion from imread to vector<cv::Vec3f> successful." << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Conversion failed." << std::endl;
}

// now test converting the vector back to a cv::Mat:
cv::Mat outFloat = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_32FC3, src.data());

// if you want to give the vector memory free later, choose this deep copy version instead:
// cv::Mat outFloat = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_32FC3, src.data()).clone();

cv::Mat out;
outFloat.convertTo(out, CV_8U);
cv::imshow("out", out);
cv::imshow("in", in);
cv::waitKey(0);


//std::cin.get();



return 0;
}
```